# Handling OnMouseWheel in a class which inherits from CAcroAXDocShim

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using MFC and I have a dockable pane to view PDF file.
I have created a class called `CCL2AcroAXDocShim` and make it inherits from `CAcroAXDocShim` and I'm trying to implement the function `OnMouseWheel` to save the current zoom level to be used when the PDF closed and opened again, but it doesn't fire at all.

```
//the header file
#include "AcroAXDocShim.h"

class CCL2AcroAXDocShim : public CAcroAXDocShim
{
public:

  /**
  * Default constructor.
  */
  CCL2AcroAXDocShim();
  /**
  * Destructor.
  */
  virtual ~CCL2AcroAXDocShim();

protected:
  DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CCL2AcroAXDocShim)

  afx_msg BOOL OnMouseWheel(UINT nFlags, short zDelta, CPoint pt); 
  //}}AFX_MSG
  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
  struct CCL2AcroAXDocShimMembers *m_pMembers;
};

//the CPP file
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CCL2AcroAXDocShim, CAcroAXDocShim)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCL2AcroAXDocShim, CAcroAXDocShim)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CCL2PDFSchematicsPage)
ON_WM_MOUSEWHEEL()
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Default constructor
CCL2AcroAXDocShim::CCL2AcroAXDocShim()
{
  m_pMembers = new CCL2AcroAXDocShimMembers;
}

// Destructor
CCL2AcroAXDocShim::~CCL2AcroAXDocShim()
{
  if (m_pMembers)
    delete m_pMembers;
}

BOOL CCL2AcroAXDocShim::OnMouseWheel(UINT nFlags, short zDelta, CPoint pt)
{
  if(nFlags & (MK_CONTROL))
  {
    m_pMembers->m_OldMouseWheel.pt = pt;
    m_pMembers->m_OldMouseWheel.nFlags = nFlags;
    m_pMembers->m_OldMouseWheel.zDelta += zDelta;
  }

  return CAcroAXDocShim::OnMouseWheel(nFlags, zDelta, pt);
}
```

and the class `CAcroAXDocShim` inherits from `CWnd` which contains the method `OnMouseWheel` 
how can I make the function `OnMouseWheel` get called? or is there another way to get the current zoom level viewed in the `CCL2AcroAXDocShim` class? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You gave us not enough information. How should we know that you are creating a ActiveX control. Seems to me, when I see the name. Check if this ActiveX control supports some events...

Comment: I've edited the question and tried to make it as clear as possible @xMRi

Comment: Where did you get CAcroAXDocShim from? It is still a mystery for me. Is it public in any way?